# speeding up CVXPY processing speed

Tags: python-3.x, cvxpy

I have written some code that uses the cvxpy library to solve an integer programming problem, however the code is taking so much time to run I was wondering if there is any way to make the code faster?

The integer programming problem in this case takes in a matrix of shape (1,569 x 3,071), and it has 3,071 constraints to satisfy. The code is as follows:

```py
mat_f = sys.argv[1]
matIdx2genome_dic_f = sys.argv[2]
genomes_f = sys.argv[3]

with open(matIdx2genome_dic_f, 'r') as in_f:
    matIdx2genome_dic = json.load(in_f)

M = np.load(mat_f)   

selection = cp.Variable(M.shape[1], boolean = True)
ones_vec = np.ones(M.shape[1])

constraints = []  
for i in range(len(M)):
    constraints.append(M[i] * selection >= 1)

total_genomes = ones_vec * selection

problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(total_genomes), constraints)
print('solving the integer programming problem: ')
time = time.time()
problem.solve(parallel = True)
print('problem solved in: '+ str(time.time() - time))

solution = selection.value
solution = list(map(round, solution))
solution = np.array(solution)

which_genomes = np.where(solution == 1.0)[0]

with open(genomes_f, 'w') as out_f:
    for idx in which_genomes:
        out_f.write(matIdx2genome_dic[idx]+'\n')
```

The first command line argument is what's important here, it's a numpy binary matrix that is of shape (1569, 3071).
The problem here is to minimize the number of columns of the matrix needed such that each and every row has at least a 1 in it's rows.

My question is how can I write this script so that it can run faster? is there a way to parallelize it? I have set the parallel parameter to True in the solve method by I don't think it's doing much since I'm monitoring the cpu utilization and it's only 100%, so I don't think that parallel option is doing much?
Or is there another way (solver that I should call maybe) that would solve this faster?

Comment: Simple things to try could be to try abd change the optimizer and to solve the problem with floating point variables (constrain then to be between 0 and 1) and use the solution rounded to nearest integer as the initial guess.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, could you please elaborate a bit more on this? as I am very new to this library.

Comment: cvxpy supports [multiple different solvers](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#choosing-a-solver). Only some of them can solve integer problems (MIP). You can specify a solver like `problem.solve(solver='ECOS_BB')`. You can specify an initial starting guess by setting `selection.value = <array with starting guess>` followed by`problem.solve(warm_start=True)`. Neither of these are guaranteed to give you any speedup though, but are worth a try.